# Can't Detect gpu after installing pytoch and python 3.6 in google Colab

Tags: python-3.x, installation, pytorch, gpu

I should run a ready project that need python 3.6.
On the other hand python of Colab is 3.10 and I install python 3.6 after that I test with following code

```
!python --version
```

and it was installed successfully and return

```
Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

after that I install pytorch compatible with this pytohn with following code

```
!conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.0 -c pytorch
```

and test it with

```
import torch
torch.cuda.is_available()
torch.cuda.device_count()
```

and return `true` and `1`
but after installing pytorch when running `!python --version` I notice version of python is not `3.6` and return to `3.10` .
However, after checking pytorch with `torch.cuda.is_available()` again and again during installation requirement and line of codes, it returns `true` .
With all these interpretations, after install all of requirement and loading data, when I run and train project, it doesn't use GPU and in logs `Device: CPU, Numer of GPUs: 0` and I noticed in resources Colab for running project, didn't use GPU rams and in following I attached screen of that.
How can I do to for using GPU when running project.